# Relatively positioned element inside sticky parent is covered inside element with overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I'm trying to re-create cell freezing just like in any popular spreadsheet program. In addition, each cell can have a dropdown with dropdown-body which should be displayed to select an option.

#### The problem

The dropdown-body is relatively positioned, wrapped in an element with absolute position. When I use this dropdown in the frozen part (which has `position: sticky`), the body is "hidden" inside the overflow viewport. I tried to adjust this by specifying *z-index* on the wrapper and the `.cell-content-wrapper` and `.cell-content` with no luck. Is there a possibility to bring the `.cell-content` to the front?

Any help appreciated.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.frozen-part {
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}

.cell-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.cell-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #7cfc00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="frozen-part">
            <div class="cell">Cell</div>
            <div class="cell">Cell</div>
            <div class="cell">
                Dropdown
                <div class="cell-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="cell-content">
                        This should be in front
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">
            Dropdown
            <div class="cell-content-wrapper">
                <div class="cell-content">
                    This is a desired behavior
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell</div>
    </div>
</div>
```